# Probability & Statistics - Event ( Explain exercise's solution)

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider tossing a die and recording the number N1 of dots facing up, then choosing
an integer N2 between 1 and N1 at random (meaning that each integer is equally
likely to be chosen).

Find the set of outcomes in the event “die shows four dots facing up.”
Solution:
{(4, 1),(4, 2),(4, 3),(4, 4),(5, 4),(6, 4)}

When i solved the exercise my answer was {(4, 1),(4, 2),(4, 3),(4, 4)}. Why we have the (5,4) and (6,4) ?

Source of exercise : http://et.engr.iupui.edu/~skoskie/ECE302/ECE302_hw1_soln_s07.pdf

Comment: I thought this, but then we must had (5,1),(5,2)...(5,5) and (6,1),(6,2) .... (6,6). But in the solution exist only this that have 4 in the N2 in the order pairs , why ?

Comment: Sorry, my earlier comment was wrong. I think the solution is incorrect, and yours is correct.

Comment: The answer is wrong or something other we must think ?

Comment: Your solution is correct. The given solution is incorrect, as you have noted.

Comment: I don't believe that is false, because the same exercise with this solution exist and the next year. If the answer was wrong they had write the correct one. I think that my solution will be correct if said N1 = 4, but now say “die shows four dots facing up.” The fact that we have N2 that is from 1..4 means that we can have N1 = 5 or N1 = 6 if we had N2 = 4.So we must check all the the sentences which we can have 4 dots on the die.We must think to reverse the pairs to contain all the sentences. Could be this that i described correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving the authors too much credit to assume they would
find a mistake within one year. (I once used a popular probability book
in which answers to one poorly stated combinatorial problem alternated
between right and wrong through four editions over about nine years --- *finally* settling on a clear statement and the right answer.)

The couplets [$(4,1),\dots,(6,6)$] in the sample space as given in your link are for $(N_1, N_2).$

I believe that the missing sentence in the questions is to say
that $N_2$ is found by rolling the die a second time.
If the second roll shows a number greater than the first, then
the couplet doesn't go into the sample space. If the second roll
shows a number the same or smaller than the first, then it does go into the sample space.

Then the question should read, "Give the outcome *in the sample space,* for which at least one roll shows 4."

You are right. The book is unclear because of a missing sentence.